# laravel 5 token with angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, token, csrf, laravel-5

AngularJs is woking

```
angular.module("myApp").run(function($http){
        $http.defaults.headers.common['mytoken'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
    })
```

Middleware Laravel 5

```
class BeforeCsrf implements Middleware {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if (Session::token() !== (string)$request->header('mytoken')){
            prin_r($request->header('mytoken'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

but `$request->header('mytoken')` not working.

Sorry my english is bad

Comment: do  inside run `console.log($('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'))` does it have any value

Comment: I try `console.log($('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'))` working with token string and I checked `console.log($http.defaults.headers.common['mytoken'])` with the same value

Answer (score -1):

**prin_r**($request->header('mytoken'));

You write prin_r instead of print_r maybe you got an error and your server is hidding the erros from you.